# Pycharm: How to use libraries installed from another project?

Tags: python, pycharm

When we create new project in pycharm, is there any way I can have libraries installed in previous projects available for this new project? I do not want to manually install all the libraries again for the new project.

Comment: Can't you just reuse the virtual env you created for that project?

Comment: I am new to pycharm, do you know how can I do that?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter

Comment: thank you, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Alt+SPress to open the project Settings/Preferences.

In the Settings/Preferences dialog Ctrl+Alt+S, select Project  | Python Interpreter. The Configure project interpreterClick the icon and select Add.

I guess this link contains the answer to your problem
[1]: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add_new_project_interpreter